# Modeling Dependent Joint Distribution

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

I'm trying to model the joint pdf of (**X**,**Y**) from example 4.5.8 of the text *[Statistical Inference 2nd Edition, Casella, Berger](https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf)* (pg 199 of the pdf). Essentially,

**X** ~ Uniform[0,1]

**Z** ~ Unfiorm[0,1/10]

**Y** ~ **X** + **Z**

I want to make a 3D plot of the joint pdf (**X**,**Y**)

Here is what I have accomplished thus far:

```
n = 1000;
X = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n];
Z = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1/10}], n];
Y = X + Z;
XY = Transpose[{X, Y}];
ListPlot[XY]
```

Which gives the plot similar to Fig 4.5.1 (b):

[image]

However, I would somehow like to use

```
Y = TransformedDistribution[
X + Z, {X \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
Z \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1/10}]}];
```

To actually make a 3D plot of the joint pdf. I know about the [Product Distribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductDistribution.html) function, but I'm not sure if it's applicable in this scenario as my random variables are not independent (**Y** depends on **X**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my random variables are not independent (**Y** depends on **X**)

You can still use `TransformedDistribution[]`:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[{x, x + z},
                               {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
                                z \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1/10}]}];

{BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; ListPlot[RandomVariate[dist, 1000]]], 
 Plot3D[PDF[dist, {x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: simulation and PDF]

Comment: This is great! Thanks for adding your code as I will hopefully be able to apply it to similar problems in the future.